# Jquery .effect stopping when called twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a JS function that finds a new element (to a ckeditor text area) and highlights it. works great, however when this method is called twice the first highlight effect stops and does not complete.

I have tried calling stop(), finish() but the animation still sticks on the previous animation
I would like to not have the first animation interrupted, and for it to complete it's animation.
Any advice appreciated.

```
function highlightContent(element){
  var newElement = CKEDITOR.instances.offer_body.document.find(element).$[0];
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#cke_offer_body").height()
  }, 1000);
  $(newElement).effect( "highlight", {color:"#29B8BE"}, 1300);
};

$(document).on("click", '#offer-item', function(){
  applyTemplate(this);
  highlightContent(".template-content");
});
```

Comment: Have you tried disabling the CKeditor (and making the textarea just a plain ol' textarea) to see if there might be some kind of conflict?

Comment: I think it's a case of a new animation starting before the previous has finished. For some reasons its not queuing the next animation

Answer (score 0):

try with stop function:

```
$(newElement).stop(true, false); //clearQueue true and jumpToEnd false
```

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: its not the newElement's animation I need to stop, its any previous elements' animations